# How to set default commit for transactions in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

```
ObjectifyBookShelfDAO transactionalDao = new ObjectifyBookShelfDAO(true);  
transactionDao.removeThis(item);   
// Its get removed only after i commit     
// Perform some operations  
transactionDao.ofy().getTxn().commit();
```

There is a scenario where in i want this object to be removed on instant... How do i do this ..

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're using [objectify-appengine](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/). as the [objectify transaction docs describe](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts#Transactions), if you make your call to `removeThis()` outside of a transaction, it will happen immediately.

as an alternative, objectify lets you mix in calls to the built in [low level java datastore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html). you could use that and call [`DatastoreService.delete()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#delete%28java.lang.Iterable%29) without passing a transaction.